# Packing technique for large data storage

Tags: classical-cipher, secure-storage

Packing multiple plaintext messages into a single ciphertext block is known to increase the effeciency of homomorphic encryption. Can someone let me know if this technique can support large data ? For example, there is packing technique [1](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01506566/document) that transform a binary vector to a polynomial of ring. However, the packing technique does not specifies what type of storage technique or file will be used to store the packed data. How we can know if a packing technique can support large message encoding and how we can ensure that the result can be stored correctly ? is there is a relation between the packing technique and the storage type of message or data ?

Comment: Is there a specific homomorphic encryption technique you have in mind? As it stands, the question is rather broad.

Comment: The problem doos not rely to the type of homomorphic encryption used. But, to the storage and computation of these packed data. For example, in the specified reference, a binary vector is transformed to a polynomial of ring. How we can know if this technique can support large data ?